# Connecting Two Android Mobile And Laptop On Same Wi-Fi Connection

Tags: android, images, windows-10, wifi

I want my two Android mobile phones to capture images and transfer them to my laptop. For this, I will connect my both phones to the hotspot made by laptop.

What software do I need on each end to make this arrangement so that as all the images are captured by mobile phones, they get transferred to laptop automatically?

Comment: For this I use [SHAREit](http://shareit.lenovo.com/) for connecting both my laptop and android mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[PhotoBackup](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=fr.s13d.photobackup)** can accomplish that on the Android end. But on the Windows side, it requires to setup a server (available for download from [the projects home page](https://photobackup.github.io/)), which might prove a bit tricky if you're not used to it. That "server software" is available for Python, Perl, NodeJS, Go and PHP – so you can pick an environment you're more familiar with.

Hence **[PhotoSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchbyte.photosync)** might be an easier solution, as it understands SMB, (S)FTP and WebDav natively – which means it can directly access Windows shares you create on the laptop, and backup to them. It can automatically backup photos & videos in the background to pre-selected targets (computer, NAS, cloud and photo services), which should fit your needs. Moreover, it can even be configured to automatically do the backup whenever you take a new picture or video. So this should meet your needs to 100%.

A third candidate might be **[Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync)**. This again would require a *client* to be installed on each participating device: note that *Sync* is based on the BitTorrent protocol, which uses peer-to-peer functionality. *Sync* also supports automatic camera backup, and thus is capable of doing the job you want to perform.